# iOS resize styled UILabel dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

I have added a `UILabel` with a fixed with and initial height to the bottom of my scrollview via the storyboard.
Via the `UIViewContoller` I give the `UILabel` a white background and rounded corners and load text into the label dynamically.

What I want to do is resize the label height based on the text.
I have read tons of posts on stackoverflow on how to do this and tried them all and none of them seem to work.

To bring down the problem I use the following code:

```
descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
descriptionLabel.text = @"Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet. Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet. Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet.";
[descriptionLabel sizeToFit];
```

The result of this is that the label will cut of the text like this:
[image]

What comes up in my mind is sizeToFit uses the initial height of the UILabel to determine the max height so in the storyboard I changed this to 250.
The result is very strange, the text is placed vertically aligned in the label, like this:

[image]

*(I can't show the whole height of the label because the scrollView cuts it off)*

If I `NSLog` the height of the `UILabel` after `sizeToFit`, I properly get to see that the height of the label is 105 pixels but the label is definitely not shown with that height.

I would highly appreciate some help because this problem is keeping me busy for a week now.

---

**Update:** Some additional info as requested.

The code that resizes the `UILabel` is called after receiving some JSON from the server via RESTkit. `viewDidLoad` executes the function that loads the data via `dispatch_async()`.

The properties of the label are:

Line breaks: word wrap
Autoshrink: Min font size (10)
Tightening letter spacing is off and **Autoresize subviews** is turned on.

The container that holds the `UILabel` is the `UIScrollView`. I autoresize the height of the scrollview **after** calling `sizeToFit`.

The view mode of the scrollview is set to **Scale to Fill** and **Autoresize subviews** is turned on.

Comment: **Where** are you placing the code that calls `sizeToFit`, and what are the autoresizing properties set to for the label and the container that holds the label (the scroll view, it looks like)?

Comment: @Nate I've added your requested info to the bottom of my question. Please let me know if you require more info.

Comment: Is the second screenshot taken after `sizeToFit` call?

Comment: @mja yes that screenshot is taken after sizeToFit when the height in the storyboard set to 250.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a few problems here.

- First of all, when you say this:

> I autoresize the height of the scrollview after calling sizeToFit. The
>   view mode of the scrollview is set to Scall to Fill and Autoresize
>   subviews is turned on.

that might be a problem.  Calling `sizeToFit` is attempting to resize your labels.  But, if you **later** resize the scroll view, **and** your scroll view is set to **Autoresize Subviews**, then it might resize the label again.  `sizeToFit` should be the *last* resizing you do on your label.

- Also, when you say *"autoresize the height of the scrollview"*, I'm not 100% sure what you mean.  What I think you should do is after you get your JSON response, determine how big the size of all your labels are, and then set the scroll view's *content size*.  The `frame` size (height) of the scroll view should not change.
- If you read [the UILabel documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth), it says:

> **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth**
>
> **Important**: If this property is set to YES, it is a programmer error to set the lineBreakMode property to a value that causes text to
>   wrap to another line.

So, you probably shouldn't be setting that property (*Autoshrink*), if the label is set to word wrap, too.

### Solution

Anyway, I know you're using storyboards, but hopefully the code example below can show you how this should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   self.scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
   self.scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

   // simulate a network delay of 4 seconds to fetch JSON
   double delayInSeconds = 4.0;
   dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
   dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      // we have the "JSON" data
      int dfltLabelHeight = 250;  // will be resized!
      int yPadding = 10;
      int y = yPadding;
      int numLabels = 8;

      for (int i = 0; i < numLabels; i++) {
         UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, y,
                                                                     self.scrollView.frame.size.width, dfltLabelHeight)];
         label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
         label.minimumFontSize = 10;
         label.autoresizesSubviews = YES;  // doesn't matter here
         //label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
         //label.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = NO;  // this crashes on iOS 6.1
         label.numberOfLines = 0;
         label.text = @"Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet. Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet. Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet.";
         [self.scrollView addSubview: label];
         [label sizeToFit];

         // re-center the label horizontally
         CGRect frame = label.frame;
         frame.origin.x = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - frame.size.width) / 2;
         label.frame = frame;

         y += yPadding + label.frame.size.height;
      }

      // adjust scroll view's virtual (content) size to fit the labels
      self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, y);
   });
}
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: thnx for your great answer. Drawing the Label programmatically after the rest of the screen was loaded did solve my problem.

Comment: Great news.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
  NSString *myText= @"Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet. Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet. Nam nisi arcu, sodales vitae scelerisque sit amet.";
  CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont: myFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, textSize.height);
  descriptionLabel.text = myText;
```